# PHP function to call another classes

Tags: php

I have seperated a few file with PHP classes, and now I need to get them together in one function like this:

```
include("require-class.php");

require_multi("db-class.php", "settings.php","users-class.php");

class ajaxLogin {
  private $settings;            
  private $users;

  public function __construct(settings $settings, users $users) {
    $this->settings = $settings;
    $this->users = $users;  
  }
}

global $ajaxLogin;
$ajaxLogin = new ajaxLogin;
```

Class in `settings.php` is named *settings* and the one in `users-class.php` is *users*. I got an error:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to
>   ajaxLogin::__construct() must be an instance of settings, none given,
>   called in /var/www/html/idcms/admin/class/login-ajax.php on line 47
>   and defined in /var/www/html/idcms/admin/class/login-ajax.php on line
>   13, referer: http://localhost/idcms/admin/

Comment: How you have called this class instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor of `ajaxLogin` requires two arguments: `$settings` and `$user`. So you need to call:

```
$ajaxLogin = new ajaxLogin($settings, $user);
```

Of course you need to instantiate `settings` and `user` before, like:

```
$settings = new settings();    // add arguments if required
$user = new user();            // add arguments if required
```

---

UPDATE

If you really want to instantiate `settings` and `user` inside your `ajaxLogin`, just remove the arguments from your `__construct` like this:

```
class ajaxLogin {
    private $settings;          
    private $users;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->settings = new settings();
        $this->users = new users();          
    }
}
```

However, the first approach is usually the better one because everyone who uses the class `ajaxLogin` knows immediately that this class depends on `settings` and `user`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901861/why-not-instantiate-a-new-object-inside-object-constructor) for more detailed answers about this.

Comment: Ok, thank you i wanted to know if there is any way to call this inside the function arguments, thank you.